# Follow Continue with Google redirect

Tags: php, google-chrome, curl

I'm to make a login script to log into a site using Google account when I open the PHP script. I can get to the first link but once I try to open the redirect link (the second CURLOPT_URL) I get stuck on the tab saying "Forwarding..." over and over. 
I'm very new to cURL but hopefully, my code gets the basic idea across what I'm wanting to do.

```
<?php
    include "simple_html_dom.php";



    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://maclab.gameful.me/signin");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://gameful.me/signin?loginSocial=google&redirect=https://maclab.gameful.me");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);



    curl_close($ch);

    echo  $response;
    exit();
?>
```

Edit: The site is used for a class and attendance is taken by logging into the site and I thought it would be more effective if a computer did it for me. Also, that link doesn't always prompt to log in and so to get the site to recognize me logging in I need to log out first and then log back in and it's really slow.

The final complete goal is that when I log in to my account on my Mac, the computer will open a tab on Chrome that browses to localhost a.k.a this script and have me automatically logged in.

Comment: What exactly is the _expected_ behavior here?  You're aware that your second setting of `CURLOPT_URL` is just overriding your first, right?  You also mention 'I get stuck on the tab saying "Forwarding..."', but there's nothing here having to do with "tabs" or the text "Forwarding", so you seem to be leaving something out.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/XH7FFil.png

Heres an image showing what I mean. Hopefully, this helps.

EDIT: I'm opening the script on Google Chrome and on an Apache2 server with PHP if that helps.

Comment: I don't see what cURL has to do with any of that.  Is `https://maclab.gameful.me/signin` _your_ page?  Or are you trying to embed someone else's site into your own?

Comment: I'm trying to make a script to log in to that site which uses Google accounts to sign in with. It's not my site, just trying to log into it with a script automatically when opening localhost on a browser. I assumed it would be possible because I've seen tutorials where they make scripts that login to sites by making a POST to an ajax.js login field. I would think it is the same concept just with signing in with a google account.

Comment: You didn't answer my question though.  "a script to log in to that site"  Is "that site" _your_ site that you own and control?

Comment: It's not my site, just trying to log into it with a script automatically when opening localhost on a browser.

Comment: Can't you just put `https://gameful.me/signin?loginSocial=google&#038;redirect=https://maclab.gameful.me` in your browser?  I'm not following what your ultimate objective is here.

Comment: Because I'm going to make the script into something that runs when I log in or boot up the computer. The site is used for a class and attendance is taken by logging into the site and I thought it would be more effective if a computer did it for me. Also, that link doesn't always prompt to log in and so to get the site to recognize me logging in I need to log out first and then log back in and it's really slow. It seems that cURL doesn't use my cookies so prompts me to log in so I do have to logout and log back in for attendance... I also kinda thought it would be an interesting project.

Comment: Please update your questions to describe in detail what you _actually_ want to accomplish.  You previously said "when opening localhost on a browser."  That contradicts what you are saying now when you say "runs when I log in or boot up the computer".  It's unlikely that you're going to be able to do this outside of a browser context.

Comment: Well no, it'll run in a browser on bootup. I'll update it anyways.

Comment: So then it's back to my previous comment.  Just have the browser load the "gameful.me" url.  You're overcomplicating this.  If it doesn't actively prompt you to log-in, then, most likely, you're _already_ logged in.  You might not want to hear it, but that's the way to do this.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose this is kinda redundant. I just thought it would be an interesting way to learn cURL. Like I said though, the fact that I'm already logged in is a problem because I have to log out and then log back in for the site to take my attendance. I guess I just have to log out before I leave for the day which sucks but not a huge deal.